# Shift a pandas DataFrame from a certain column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation, shift

I am trying to manipulate a Pandas DataFrame. See the Pandas DataFrame below:
[image]

I am trying to shift from column 6 by a period of 1 if column 6 is missing.

Here is the idea:

```
tarrif_6_missing = df2[6].isnull()
df2[tarrif_6_missing] = df2[tarrif_6_missing].shift(1,axis=1)
```

The above is incorrect because it shifts the whole cells from the start of the columns. Instead if column 6 is missing. I would like to shift the columns by a period of 1 from the column 6 not from the start of the column.

EDIT: Thanks for the edits, but I am getting through, getting an error:

```
tarrif_6_missing = df2.loc[:,6].isnull()
df2.loc[:,tarrif_6_missing:] = df.loc[:,tarrif_6_missing:].shift(1, axis=1)
```

I get an error: `TypeError: '0       False`

And it does not go through

Comment: I'd be useful to also have an example of what you would like the result to look like. Does "shift by a period of 1" mean downwards or upwards, i.e., are you filling the holes or making them one longer?

Comment: Index goes first, then the columns, i.e. 
`loc[tarrif_6_missing, column_6_name:] = ...`

Answer (score 3):

You can use .loc[] to act select a subpart of dataframe to shift like this:

```
 df.loc[:,column_index:]=df.loc[:,column_index:].shift(1, axis=1)
```

Comment: I am getting an error: df2[tarrif_6_missing]
tarrif_6_missing = df2.loc[:,6].isnull()
df2.loc[:,tarrif_6_missing:] = df.loc[:,tarrif_6_missing:].shift(1, axis=1)

Comment: df.loc[tarrif6missing,6]=df.loc[tarrif6missing,6].shift(1, axis=1) i think

Comment: Probably, irrelevant here, but once I got a weird error trying to shift horizontally, while
`df.T.shift(1).T` worked perfectly. Just for your information.